# Merging Pandas Dataframes averiging values where both have values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two Dataframes.

```
print(df1)
  key  value
0   A  2
1   B  3
2   C  2
3   D  3

print(df2)
  key  value
0   B  3
1   D  1
2   E  1
3   F  3
```

What I want is for it to do a outer merge on key and pick whichever value is not NaN.
Which one it choses if both are int (or float) is not that important. The mean would be a nice touch though.

```
print(df3)
  key  value
0   A  2
1   B  3
3   C  2
4   D  2
5   E  1
6   F  3
```

I tried:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='outer')
```

but it generates 2 new columns. I could just do my calculations after, but am sure there is an easier solution, that I just could not find.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2]).dropna()` you could chain this with a drop_duplicate but your requirements aren't very clear, also if you have an outer merge your missing keys? your output doesn't match your requirement atmo, `B` should have a value of `1`?

Comment: Oh my bad. Sorry, I will update my question.

Comment: check out `combine_first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, the duplicates are dropped in order of the dataframe entry, so the dupes from df1 are dropped and df2 are kept, if any keys don't match the duplicate key or both happen to be na we can drop them `.dropna()`

```
dfs = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['key'],keep='last').dropna(how='any')


 key  value
0   A      2
2   C      2
3   D      3
0   B      3
1   D      1
2   E      1
3   F      3
```